# Why this assignment is possible?

Tags: c++

I'm reading the source code of tensorflow, and I get lost with below assignment.

```
begin.flat<int32>()(7) = 10;
```

What's `begin.flat<int32>()(7)`?

Comment: Can anyone explain it here, I googled and get nothing. I'm not familar with c++

Comment: Explain it is more than just downvote.

Comment: It's unfair to downvoe without reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In abstract terms,

`begin.flat<int32>()(7)` returns a *reference* to something, and that something is set to 10 by the assignment. It's *probably* an element of the tensor.

`begin.flat<int32>()` returns something that has an overloaded `()` operator that takes a numeric parameter. It's *probably* an extraction of one row or column of a matrix in the tensor to a vector-like instance.

`begin` is an object that has a `template` function called `flat` that takes no parameters. In writing `<int32>` explicitly you are wanting to use an explicit template instantiation of that function. `begin` itself is probably a reference to a *matrix* extracted from the tensor.

There's not much else to say. You'll need to study the documentation for more details. But C++ is such an expressive language - much can be gleaned from reading the code.

Comment: Can I take it as `begin.flat<int32>() ` return a pointer to a function?

Comment: No. I don't think it would be designed like that. It's more likely to be a vector-type class.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explaination, though I'm not fully understand it. But I'm much clear now.